# CSS nth-child only on parent element not nested

Tags: html, css

I want to add a background image only to the **first table - 2nd tr** tag. To do that I am using the HTML and CSS below:

```css
table tr:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: #00FFFF;
  background-image: url("images/bg_02.jpg");
  background-position: 50% 50%;
}
```

```html
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" width="600px" style="max-width : 600px; width : 100%; margin : 0 auto;">
  <tr>
    <td style="line-height: 0px;">
      <img style="width : 100%; height : auto;  display: block;" src="images/mailing_01.jpg" alt="bottle one">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <h2 style="padding : 0; line-height : 100%; font-size : 39px; font-family: Gatorade; text-transform: uppercase; text-align : center; ">¡Ponte al día con Gatorade!</h2>
            <h3 style="font-size : 23px; font-family: ProximaNova; text-transform: uppercase; text-align: center;">(Nombre de la persona), <br/>¡Ya está aquí la nueva Gatorade Zero!</h3>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <img src="images/bottles.png" alt="bottles">
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

But I can see it's adding the background image to **second table - the second tr** too which I don't want.

How can I fix it, please?

Comment: Give the parent table a class and use it. `.class > tr:nth-child()` etc.

Comment: Ah..Yes, That could be a solution :)

Comment: This is more of a frame-challenge, but I'd argue that you shouldn't be using the `<table>` element here, since the content isn't tabular data.

Comment: @DavidThomas I am going to use this for an HTML email template.